# how to redirect large file requests through node.js to a different server using request

Tags: node.js, express, request

I have a node.js server that is forwarding API requests through to another server on a different port (so that auth cookies and the like make it across), and this has all worked great until the client has needed to upload a large file (> 100mb).

When I try to do that, if the file is over ~30mb the request never even reaches the far server (which will happily accept large files when connected to directly), so I'm pretty sure it's dying in node ... somewhere.

```
"use strict";
const http = require("http");
const port = process.env.FRONTEND_PORT || 13370;
const path = require("path");
const request = require("request");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

const staticPath = path.join(__dirname, "/dist/");
app.set("port", port);

// Attempt to set some ridiculously high limits on things
app.use(express.urlencoded({parameterLimit: 1000000, limit: '10gb', extended: true}));
app.use(express.json({limit: '10gb'}));

// Serve files from this location
app.use(express.static(staticPath));

app.use(
  '/api',
  (req, res) =>
  {
    var url = "https://localhost:12121/api" + req.url;
    req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    console.log(res.statusMessage);
  });


// If we hit any path that doesn't exist, instead serve up index.html and let react router handle it
app.get("*", (req, res) => { res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/dist/index.html")); });

app.listen(app.get("port"), () => { console.log("listening"); });
```

As you can see, I've tried bumping up the limits (based on other SO answers I've seen) using:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({parameterLimit: 1000000, limit: '10gb', extended: true}));
app.use(express.json({limit: '10gb'}));
```

...but this doesn't seem to be helping me in this case. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I am extremely new to node.js (and, honestly, web development in general).

(It's also worth noting, the file is being sent through a basic XMLHttpRequest as POST, sending a File object through - nothing fancy going on there)